# How to query and handle a UUID created with go.uuid and inserted into PostgreSQL 11?

Tags: go, uuid, postgresql-11

I inserted in PostgreSQL table an UUID created with go.uuid :

```
import (
        "github.com/satori/go.uuid"
) 

func main() {
        usid := uuid.Must(uuid.NewV4())
        fmt.Println("usid := uuid.Must(uuid.NewV4")
        fmt.Println(usid.String())
        res, err := stmt.Exec(cn, csn, ccn, id)
        if err != nil || res == nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
}

    sStmt := "insert into basicuserinfo (cn, csn, ccn, appUserAccountID ) 
    values ($1, $2, $3, $4)"
    stmt, err := db.Prepare(sStmt)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer stmt.Close()
    fmt.Println("# Inserting values")
```

And actually a row is inserted in the postgreSQL db:

```
           cn  |  csn  |  ccn | id
                              | 2412fcd3-8712-4a0f-830a-d77bd4cf2195
```

In order to query with golang variables I tried first, to use a prepared statement.
First, using db.PrepareContext :

```
    sel := "SELECT appUserAccountID FROM basicuserinfo WHERE cn = $1 AND csn 
    = $2 AND ccn = $3"

     stmt, err = db.PrepareContext(ctx,sel)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var utenteID string
    err = stmt.QueryRowContext(ctx,cn, csn, ccn).Scan(&utenteID)
    log.Printf("ID= %s\n", utenteID)
    fmt.Println("aaaaaaaaa") // Just to check that the this line gets executed
```

Whose execution remains "idle", in stand-by, without ending and producing any output:

```
marco@pc01:~/go/marcoGolang/goPostgres$ go run pqExample00.go
# Inserting values
```

Then I tried in this way, with db.Prepare():

```
    stmt, err = db.Prepare(sel)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
    res, err = stmt.Exec(cnv, csnv, ccnv)
```

In this second case the execution seems ending successfully, but I do not know how to convert the sql.Result into a correct form which can be handled, for example simply displayed with fmt.Println() or getting other handlings.
So... how to correctly query and handle a UUID created with go.uuid and inserted into PostgreSQL 11?

Looking forward to your kind help.
Marco

Comment: @mkopriva I added a screenshot showing the idle state and I corrected what I wrote before

Comment: What is printing "Inserting values" that's visible in the screenshot? Are you executing the correct program? There is not such print statement in your example code and besides that code is selecting values not "inserting" them.

Comment: There is no column named `appUserAccountID`. What's the error returned by QueryRowContext? The Exec method family is for statements that don't return result sets, such as UPDATE and DELETE. Use one of the QueryRow* methods if you want to retrieve results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a reason for using PrepareContext, you could just do this?

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connectionString)

sel := "SELECT appUserAccountID FROM basicuserinfo WHERE cn = $1 AND csn = $2 AND ccn = $3"

var idn string
err = db.QueryRow(sel, cn, csn, ccn).Scan(&idn)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("idn: %v\n", idn)
```

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for the catch on the Conn and errors, copy-paste error, fixed

Comment: Thanks a lor @snassr and@mkopriva for your kind patient help. Marco